# Resolve Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token >

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I'm have a function to transform text in a base64 image on my Cordova App. It's working fine but in a few devices there's an Unexpected token error on the script.

Here's the function:

```
    function socialShare(message, font) {
    var y = 12;
    var x = 18;
    var canvas = document.getElementById("receipt");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    // calcula a largura da string mais larga
    context.font = font;
    var maxStrWidth = message.map(e => {
        return context.measureText(e).width;
    }).sort((a, b) => {
        return b - a;
    });

    // configura a largura do canvas dinamicamente
    canvas.width = maxStrWidth[0] + 9;
    canvas.height = x * message.length;

    // seta a cor do background do canvas
    context.fillStyle = "#ffffe6";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // escreve o texto
    context.font = font;
    context.fillStyle = "#000";
    message.forEach(e => {
        context.fillText(e, 3, y);
        y += x;
    });

    // gera a string base64
    let base64 = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1);

    // chamada do plugin social share
    window.plugins.socialsharing.share(
        null, 
        'Comprovante de Aposta', 
        base64, 
        null
    );
}
```

The error is thrown on the **var maxStrWidth** line. Do you see anything wrong with it?

Comment: It seems those devices don't support fat-arrow syntax. Try adding an empty fat-arrow function somewhere above that line and see if it errors out on the new line. Which devices/browsers does this fail for?

Comment: The error appears on a bunch of different devices but they're mostly 4.X.X and very little 5.5.1 Android. I'm debugging the app with Chrome Inspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all devices support the ES6 arrow functions, this is especially true for older android versions that use an older chrome webview version.

If you intend on supporting older devices it may be better to stick with standard function declarations.

Further reading here:

https://strongloop.com/strongblog/an-introduction-to-javascript-es6-arrow-functions/

Comment: I changed for the standard declaration:

message.forEach(e = function() {
        context.fillText(e, 3, y);
        y += x;
    });

Now I get: **ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side**

Comment: That is because you have the syntax wrong for your forEach function. e = function() should be changed to function(e){} so inside the function e with be the current message value.

Comment: Passing the function as parameter like this?

message.forEach(function(e) {
        context.fillText(e, 3, y);
        y += x;
    });

Comment: Oh, I was wrong, the error is here: var maxStrWidth = message.map(e = function() {
        return context.measureText(e).width;
    }).sort((a, b) = function() {
        return b - a;
    });     What can I do?

Comment: Again you should pass e in as an argument. e = function should be function(e){}

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks dude!

Comment: No worries anytime! Glad I could help.