# Cordova brightness still returns -1

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I added cordova brightness plugin ( https://github.com/mgcrea/cordova-plugin-brightness ), i need to set higher brightness for QR code reading, and than, i need to set brightness to the "default" value. 
I read a brightness and set the new one like this:

```
let brightnessValue: number = 0.7;
this.brightness.getBrightness().then((brightness) => {
  this.bright = brightness;
});
this.brightness.setBrightness(brightnessValue);
```

and than i want to set it back

```
this.brightness.setBrightness(this.bright);
```

but value in my `this.bright` variable is -1. Althought brightness on my mobile phone was set by me, it always returns -1.(Trying on Android 6, Xiaomi Redmi 3S) Does anyone has an idea, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have copied my answer from here as I think it applies to your question. I think it all depends on whether or not you have an up to date webview or not.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43746807/7837081

> Not all devices support the ES6 arrow functions, this is especially true for older android versions that use an older chrome webview version.
>
> If you intend on supporting older devices it may be better to stick with standard function declarations.
>
> Further reading here:
>
> https://strongloop.com/strongblog/an-introduction-to-javascript-es6-arrow-functions/